# What does "wil(d)in'" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english, dialects

In Rihanna's song "FourFiveSeconds", this line is sung in the chorus:

> Now I'm four, five seconds from **wilin'**...

I searched on Google for the definition of "wilin'" and got this:

> **wildin'** (also **wilin'**) *verb*
>
> to have fun, act crazy with a group of friends

*Source: Online Slang Dictionary*

Whilst this definition sounds accurate, I would like to know if there are any other meanings.

Also, how common is "wildin'" in spoken American English, and in what dialect or culture?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Park_jogger_case

Comment: From 1993 - [*they often went out "wilding" - that is, **attacking people** in the park at night.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+out+wilding%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: What did you find out when you looked in other dictionaries?  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wilding has multiple definitions.  You might also look up "wild," and see what you get.
I'm American, and I have almost never heard this word.

Comment: "Wilding" is (or at least used to be) a rarely-used term with a range of meanings centered around doing wild, outrageous things and being "out of control".  It is sufficiently rare that it no doubt it acquires localized meanings of a more specific nature.

Answer (score 3):

*Wilding* is a term that gained media use in the 1980s and 90s to describe gangs of teenagers committing violent acts, particularly against property or each other.

It has more recently was supplanted by the phrase "violent flash mob," but still make some headline appearances as in [this 2013 New York Daily News article](http://m.nydailynews.com/news/national/wilding-episode-strikes-fear-downtown-chicago-article-1.1304652). For older terms, cf. "mob violence" or "rumble."

See also [sense 2](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wilding) at dictionary.com

Comment: You think that is the meaning meant in the song?

Comment: In the context of other lyrics like. "Hold me back, I'm about to spaz" and " if I go to jail tonight, promise you pay my bail" I do. What remains open as a question, imho, is whether she would put together a riot or just go wild as an individual.

Answer (score 2):

[Wilding](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/wilding):

> - to have fun, act crazy with a group of friends. Note: also pronounced as "wilin'".
>     (Submitted by Kesha Edwards from Charlotte, NC, USA on Jun 04 1997.)

(onlineslangdictionary.com)

Origin and usage appear to be mainly from U.S.,  my assumption is that it is a slang verb form of the more common adjective '*wild*'.

[AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=wild) cites the verb *to wild* with the meaning:

> - (intr.v.)  wild·ed, wild·ing, wilds.
> - To go about in a group threatening, robbing, or attacking others.

Comment: OP didn't ask for these. He already gave the definition and mentioned that it is US English.

Answer (score 1):

From what little I know it would suggest an act of violence (such as punching the wall, etc.), which works if her song speaks of worried family.

Answer (score 1):

To me it means Not having wild fun but rather like in Kanye's refrain "hold me back I'm about to spaz." Both of their phraseology e's mean the same thing.